# limit aws ecs(fargate) manually launched tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Is there an accepted mechanism, option or setting whereby a manually launched task (not service!) in an AWS would "queue up" if a certain limit is reached. For example, if limit is 10 and an 11th task is manually launched, it waits for one of the previous tasks to stop before running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no mechanism like this. You would have to build something like this yourself. You could add task definitions to an SQS queue, and have a Lambda function that pulls a task definition, runs some API calls against ECS to get the number of running tasks, and then launches the task if your limit hasn't been met.